# Equation conditions

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am in doubt of how to properly write (multiple) conditions to an equation. Right now I have

```
a+b=c,\quad a>0,b\ge 0
```

Which gives

[image: this]

But I dont think it looks very nice. How can I make it look better?

If you want to reference an example in a journal or elsewhere, I would be gracious for that as well.

Comment: In cases like these, until such a time when someone tells you 'the standard practice', I usually create an abstraction (i.e. `\newcommand`) on top of the idea so that presentation can be changed later.  Mathematically speaking, wouldn't you simply write `\forall a>0,b>0;\;a+b=c`?

Answer (score 3):

You could stack the conditions by the `aligned` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \[
    a+b=c,\quad \begin{aligned} a&>0,\\ b&\ge 0\end{aligned}
  \]
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking to express the thought "the set of all points `a` and `b` for which `a+b=c`, `a>0`, and `b\ge0`? If so, you could formalize it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\{\, a,b \mid a+b=c, a>0, b\ge 0 \,\}$
\end{document}
```

[image]